# ¿Alguien sabe por qué no puedo añadir registro a una base de datos utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

El problema es que solo puedo consultar información de una tabla de una base de datos, pero al momento de querer insertar algún registro el archivo PHP no arroja ningún error, pero no ocurre nada en la base de datos, solo cuando ingreso el registro de manera manual mediante la consola SQL de phpMyAdmin. He intentado de muchas maneras y asegurándome de que la conexión sea adecuada y todo parece estar bien, pero al ejecutar el archivo PHP e intentar añadir un registro en la tabla no ocurre nada, alguien sabe que está ocurriendo?

Comment: sin el código involucrado es difícil ayudar, por favor lee [ask], edita y mejora tu pregunta además coloca un título descriptivo del problema en cuestión

Comment: "He intentado de muchas maneras" ... muestra un par de las muchas y vemos que está pasando

Comment: Es posible que el usuario que estás utilizando para la conexión no tenga los permisos necesarios para hacer un insert.